# Is a function that calls itself only once no matter the input recursive?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Consider a function that does an operation and calls itself at most  once (not more than one “recursion” level) no matter what the input is. 
Is this function considered recursive?

Example:

```
join1 :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
join1 [Just x] = [x]
join1 [Nothing] = []
join1 (x) = concat (map join1 (map (\k->[k]) x))
```

In this case, when calling:
    Join1 [nothing, just 2, just 3,...]
The join1 function will be called on each element, entering immediately the termination condition

Comment: How is it supposed to call itself once no matter the input? If that is the case that call will result in a second call, a third one, etc.

Comment: The answer would have to be "yes", because any function that calls itself, even (as is the case with most recursive functions) only for some inputs, is by definition recursive. However, as @WillemVanOnsem points out your situation is a logical contradiction.

Comment: The input matters for your example. It doesn't always call itself.

Comment: I added an example in the question. In this case, join1 will call itself in the map but won’t ever go more that one level below because it will be called either with [Just x] or [Nothing]

Comment: @adrien: well then the input definitely matters. Furthermore this will in fact call `join1` multiple times: once per item in the list.

Comment: @willem I edited the question. The intent was that it doesn’t go deeper than one level no matter the input.

Comment: Is a loop that never iterates more than twice still considered a loop? I don't see why not. I think the real question is, *should* this function be recursive, or would it be better to write it in a way that isn't?

Comment: It does not make sense to call `join1` here and wrap values in lists. It is definitely more elegant and cleaner to make a helper function that unwraps the `Just`s. We can replace the above with `join1 = concatMap f where f (Just x) = [x]; f Nothing = []`.

Comment: If you want to implement a recursive function (as per homework, etc.). I suggest that you implement the recursion over the list itself, since a list in Haskell is a recursive data structure (and `map`, `concat`, are all implemented through recursion).

Comment: @willem it’s more like the opposite, implementing it without recursion. Your solution with the where is definitely more elegant, however I’m wondering if the solution that I gave as an example can be considered recursive. Technically, as it will always call the termination condition (actually, even with a different input parameter type as it will be always called with a single element list), it doesn’t enter a true recursion. But if we consider “calling itself” as a recursion definition, it would be recursive.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is recursive. The number of calls at runtime and the runtime recursion depth is irrelevant. A definition `x = expression` is said to be recursive if `x` appears in `expression`, referring to the `x` we are defining right now.

Briefly put, "recursiveness" is a syntactic property of the definition, and does not consider the runtime behavior.

As a silly example, this definition is recursive, even if it never calls itself at runtime. Even if it could trivially simplified into a non-recursive one.

```
identity :: a -> a
identity x = (\_ -> x) identity
```

Comment: of course, it *would* call itself (ad infinitum) at runtime in a non-lazy language

Comment: @RobinZigmond To be pedantic, I think even -say- in JavaScript the above would work since I never _call_ the function. But, in general, you are completely correct, since I could define `identity x = (\_ -> x) (identity x)` which would definitely not work in a strict language.

Comment: it seems you're right, I just tried in the browser console (Chrome) `function identity(x) {return (function(y) {return x;})(identity)}` and the function does indeed work fine as the identity function. I guess modern JS engines realise that since the inner function doesn't use its argument then there's no need to evaluate it - but I thought that the "strict" definition of "strict evaluation" means that all expressions need to be evaluated as soon as encountered, which would indeed lead to this function infinitely recursing.

Comment: and you're correct that replacing the `identity` with `identity(x)` does lead to "infinite" recursion (actually a call-stack error) - which I guess means I don't really understand JS's evaluation strategy, since if it really was a case of the engine figuring out that there was no need to evaluate the argument then this would cause no recursion either.

Comment: oh nevermind, I see the difference, `identity` is just a function value, which it doesn't really make sense to talk about "evaluating". When you actually call that function, that's what forces the evaluation. (Sorry for missing the obvious, which you even explicitly stated by emphasising the word "call")

Answer (score 0):

You have underestimated the valid inputs for your function. What if you call it like:

```
join1 [Nothing, Just [Just 2, Nothing, Just 3], Just [Nothing, Just 4]]
```

Or going the other way, what if you call it like:

```
join1 [Nothing]
```

Non-infinite recursive function calls are always limited in depth. Calling itself once or even zero times for any specific input is perfectly valid.  In fact, it won't terminate if you don't allow input with zero recursive calls.